"H14 No web processes running" after run Prometheus on Heroku
I have a problem with running Prometheus using Docker container on Heroku.
This is my Dockerfile:
FROM prom/prometheus:v2.51.2

COPY prometheus.yml /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
COPY web.yml /etc/prometheus/web.yml
ENV TZ=Europe/Warsaw

CMD prometheus --web.enable-admin-api --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml --web.config.file=/etc/prometheus/web.yml --web.listen-address=:$PORT

After release my container, I have an error: code=H14 desc="No web processes running".
Maybe some of you ran Prometheus on Heroku and have a Dockerfile ready?
I think I have a little mistake in "CMD" command in my Dockerfile, but I don't know where.
